# A chess problem: White to play and mate in two

Tags: checkmate, problems

**White's turn, checkmate in two moves**

```
[FEN "r1b2k1r/1p2bppp/p1B2q2/8/8/8/PPPQ1P1P/2KRR3 w - - 0 1"]
```

How does White deliver checkmate in 2 moves?

Comment: I've seen this position before. Could it be the first annotated game in Nimzowitsch's "My system"?

Comment: That's a good one for students.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple one:

> 1. Qd8+ Bxd8 2. Re8#

Answer (score 1):

There is piece that is not allowing mate by white. Just force this piece to move.

> Qd8+ Bxd8 Re8#

Answer (score 1):

White can back-rank(sort of)Black after 1. Qd8!. This move deflects the bishop onto d8(only legal move), allowing 2. Re8#.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a simple brute force (i.e. sacrifices and/or checks) tactic that teaches how to see back-rank weaknesses and how to open up lines.

Solution:

> 1. Qd8+! (A forcing move that gives Black no move but to respond to) Bxd8 (The only legal move available) 2. Re8# (This shows the point giving up the queen-to force the Black bishop to open up the e-file as to allow the rook to move and give a mate that takes advantage of the Black king’s extremely bad position and misplaced pieces.)